# I get SMS notifications but the new text message is not shown

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, sms

My phone will notify me that I have a message, but when I go into the messaging app that message won't be there.  When I send a message off it also won't show me the message after it sent.  I restarted it and cleared the messaging data and that didn't work.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you using the built-in messaging app?  Have you tried a different one like [Handcent](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.handcent.nextsms) or [Google Messenger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.messaging)?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that your time/date settings are correct. This may cause the Google Play suite of applications to misbehave as well.

Answer (score 0):

To add on to Matthew's comment, go to settings> device> default applications and take a look at what is set as your default messaging app.

The app listed there *should* be the one receiving the SMS and sending you the notifications.  If you're not seeing the messages listed there, we'll be happy to help you track down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just download 3rd party text messaging app "[Textra](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.textra&hl=fr)", make that app as default messaging app ann reboot the phone, then all the messages will be shown. Just delete all the messages from that app and issue will be sorted out.

Comment: What's your relationship with this app? It's OK to mention your own apps on this site (when relevant to the question), but you have to say if you're doing that, so that other visitors can judge how to take the recommendation.

Comment: Than you "Textra" is installed in my device, It repairs my mobile. Now inbox showing all messages